# Why filtering the result of an observable subscription gives a different result than filtering observable itself

Tags: javascript, filter, rxjs, observable

I am using this code:

```
var rx = require('rxjs');
var fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');

var urls = [
  'http://gundam.wikia.com/api/v1/Navigation/Data'
];

var gundams = rx.Observable
  .from(urls)
  .flatMap(x => fetch(x))
  .flatMap(x => x.json())
  .map(x => x.navigation.wiki)
  .filter(x => x.text === "Mobile Weapons");

gundams.subscribe(
  (n) => console.log(n),
  (e) => console.log(e),
  (d) => console.log('done')
);
```

and I currently get no result logged to the console (except for 'done').

If I remove the last chain on my observable object (`.filter(x => x.text === "Mobile Weapons");`) and change

`(n) => console.log(n),`

to

`(n) => console.log(n.filter(x => x.text === "Mobile Weapons")),`

I get the expected result logged to the console

`[ { text: 'Mobile Weapons',
    href: '/wiki/Special:RunQuery/Weapon_query',
    children: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] } ]`

I am probably just misunderstanding how observables work, but I am curious how I can change my code to not have to use filter within the subscribe callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `map` is returning the array of objects, so your filter function receives the array and not the contents of the array that you're trying to filter on.

This is the same reason the filter works when you do it in subscribe. Since map is returning the array of objects you're able to filter that array and it works as expected.

You need to use `flatMap` so that filter receives the items within the array instead of the array.

```
var urls = [
  'http://output.jsbin.com/qimutofedi.json'
];

var gundams = Rx.Observable
  .from(urls)
  .flatMap(x => fetch(x))
  .flatMap(x => x.json())
  .flatMap(x => x.navigation.wiki) // <--- flatten out the array to emit its values
  .filter(x => x.text === "Mobile Weapons");

gundams.subscribe(
  (n) => console.log(n),
  (e) => console.log(e),
  (d) => console.log('done')
);
```

The above will log:

```
Object {text: "Mobile Weapons", href: "/wiki/Special:RunQuery/Weapon_query",children: Array[4]}
children:Array[4]
href:"/wiki/Special:RunQuery/Weapon_query"
text:"Mobile Weapons"
__proto__:Object
```

[jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/gerofubuxo/edit?html,js,console,output)